# Kotlin Gradle include runtime when building jar

Tags: kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to include the kotlin runtime when building my jar with gradle. I cannot find an update to date thread anywhere online that shows how to do this.

Currently I have tried the following

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile>().configureEach {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = freeCompilerArgs + "-include-runtime"
        jvmTarget = "16"
    }
}
```

This builds the jar fine but doesn't include the runtime like I would expect. How can I configure gradle to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "include runtime"? Include Kotlin stdlib in a resulting jar file? Usually, we don't put everything into a single jar file, but use several jar files instead. If you need to put all dependencies into a single jar, search for plugin that creates a "fat jar".

Comment: Yes sorry I'm new to Kotlin. I want the stdlib included in the resulting jar so it can standalone work with java projects that don't use Kotlin

Comment: This is not the standard way of including dependencies to your library in Java/Kotlin world. If you create a library using Gradle (or Maven) and you use it from another Maven/Gradle project, it will automatically include Kotlin's stdlib for you. But if you really, really need to distribute your library as a simple jar file then as I said - you need to create a so called fat jar. You should find several plugins that can do it.

Comment: Are you creating a _library_, or an _application_?

Comment: A library that's being loaded into an application using the jvm that doesn't have the kotlin runtime, hence, why I NEED to have the kotlin runtime bundled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the shadowJar plugin.  Add

```
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
```

To your plugins, then run `./gradlew shadowJar` to create a jar file in `build/lib` containing the kotlin runtime as well as any of your runtime dependencies